# Constructing a dispersion relation from the Hamiltonian

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, dispersion

I'll begin by saying that I'm not entirely clear on if this is possible. I have a Hamiltonian of the form
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{$\omega $1} & \text{J12} & 0 & \text{J14} \\
 \text{J12} & \text{$\omega $2} & \text{J23} & 0 \\
 0 & \text{J23} & \text{$\omega $3} & \text{J34} \\
 \text{J14} & 0 & \text{J34} & \text{$\omega $4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which comes from the Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_i{\hbar\omega_i(\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_i+\frac{1}{2})} + \sum_{i}{\hbar J_{i,i+1}\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_{i+1}}+hc$$

with a periodic boundary condition. This is a system of coupled harmonic oscillators. I'm trying to construct the dispersion curve, which I am sure I have done before, but somehow I can't find a reference for it nor do I remember exactly how to proceed. Something with fourier, so that the +1 term turns into a sine or a cosine, but apart from that I am a litle stuck. As the J values are not equal the problem is a little more complex than usually; maybe it can be solved with Mathematica or something? That would be ideal, but I could also first look at the case where they are all equal.

After some thinking and useful comments, it is obvious that I can't do this analytically in the case of general J and omega. In the case where they are all equal it is relatively straightforward. I am however still interested in solving this numerically in general, to get a numerical curve to fit data to. I would also like to think about the generalisation

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{$\omega $1} & \text{J12} & J13 & \text{J14} \\
 \text{J12} & \text{$\omega $2} & \text{J23} & J24 \\
J13 & \text{J23} & \text{$\omega $3} & \text{J34} \\
 \text{J14} & J24 & \text{J34} & \text{$\omega $4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Which corresponds to the hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_i{\hbar\omega_i(\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_i+\frac{1}{2})} + \sum_{i\neq j}{\hbar J_{i,j}\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_{j}}+hc$$
but I suppose if there is a technique for the first it will work for the second.

Comment: For the case where $J_{i,i+1} = J$, try exploring the canonical transformation $a_i = \sum_{k=1}^N \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi ik/N} b_k$. In the general case I do not think an analytical solution will be possible. Indeed, a Fourier transformation to momentum space will obviously not work in general since when the $J_{i,i+1}$ are different the problem is not translation-invariant.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you know where to start for a numerical approach as well? I'll look at the transformation first though.

Comment: Well the Hamiltonian is quadratic, i.e. it can be written as $H = \sum_{i,j} M_{ij} a_i^\dagger a_j + \mathrm{const.}$ This means that the problem is reduced to diagonalising the matrix $M_{ij}$, whose eigenvalues give you the dispersion relation of the elementary excitations.

Comment: Indeed, that is true. I've analyzed these eigenvalues for a certain numerical setup, and I'm actually trying to fit a function to them, which is why I'm trying to find the dispersion curve. However, you are probably right that this quickly becomes impossible analytically. I'll just have to look at the simplest case.

Comment: Does it make sense that I find something like $2N^2 J cos({2\pi/N})$?

Comment: I think you need a momentum argument inside the cosine (i.e. $\cos(2\pi k /N)$) and the factor of $N^2$ probably comes from incorrect normalisation of the transformation I gave you. You need $[b_k,b_l^\dagger] = \delta_{kl}$. But in general yes, the sinusoidal dispersion relation is exactly what you expect from a free lattice Hamiltonian. It makes sense: long-wavelength excitations do not see the underlying lattice and so have a dispersion relation like $p^2/(2m)$, whereas the short-wavelength excitations have reduced kinetic energy due to Bragg reflection from the lattice.

Comment: Yeah, there should have been a $k$, and it is $N$ not $N^2$. Thank you for your help; this model gives quite a good fit. Now I just need to think of a way to find the corresponding $k$ value from the eigenvectors belonging to the eigenvalues. I suppose doing a Fourier transform should show a peak at the corresponding $k$ value.

Comment: I do not think you should have any prefactor $N$, since this would mean that the bandwidth increases with the number of lattice sites, which is not the correct behaviour. About finding the momentum $k$, for sure you could Fourier transform the eigenfunctions. However, note that in the absence of translation invariance it does not make too much sense to assign a momentum to the eigenstates, since it is not a good quantum number.

Comment: Hm. But in the case where all J and Omega are equal, there would be translation invariance, no? As I set it up to have periodic boundary conditions, with the $J_{1,4}$ terms. 

I'm not so sure about the $N$ term. Physically your argument makes sense, but I have to see what went wrong in the calculation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. In the translation-invariant case the momentum is given basically by $p_k = \hbar 2\pi k/(\Delta N)$, where $\Delta$ is the lattice spacing. Regarding the $N$, I think you should get a factor of $1/N$ from the product of two $b$ operators, which should each carry a $1/\sqrt{N}$ normalisation. This will cancel with a $N \delta_{kk^\prime}$ when you perform the summation over lattice sites.